# Reactjs - Redirect from react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, bootstrap-4

When I use Redirect in my react app, it redirects to a specific path, and when I reload that page, the bootstrap mess up as if it was not there. This only happens when I use Redirect!

App.js

```
<Route exact path="/itemSelection" component={itemSelection/:id} />
```

Login.js

```
if (this.state.login) {
    return (<Redirect to={`/itemSelection/${this.state.id}`}/>)
}
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant parts of your code. Without that you will be unlikely to get any helpful answers. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @trixn Thank you for your reply. I just added the relevant code and itemSelection is just a regular React component with a couple of divs and Bootstrap classes.

Comment: What does "bootsrap messes up" mean? Does the page appear as if the styles where not loaded correctly? Check the static files in the "Sources" tab of your developer console. How is your react app served? Through a development server? I'm afraid there are so many possible reasons. The provided information is not enough to answer your question. The code does not contain an obvious mistake.

Comment: It's served locally, custom styles only is loaded and the bootstrap does exist in the sources but isn't loading. This just happens when I add another path dynamically like (/itemSelection/:id) in the Route and in the Redirect I add (/itemSelection/2)

Comment: That means you dynamically add another `<Route>` component? Are you aware that any dynamically added routes are gone when reloading the browser tab? That means that the redirect probably points into nowhere unless you recreate the missing `<Route>` again. Usually routes are static. There are only very few usecases for dynamically generated routes. Could you also share the relevant code?

Comment: Also install the [`react-developer-tools`](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) and inspect your component tree. Are the components you expect correctly rendered? You can see that in the "React" tab that will appear in the developer console after installing the plugin.

Comment: *updated the question* Yes, it's rendered correctly. The thing is everything works just fine when it redirects but when I reload the page, the bootstrap is just gone!

Comment: Do you have any initialization of bootstrap elements inside a component? Be aware that any context of your app will be gone after a reload. There is little else I can say. The problem is obviously not in the code you provided. Maybe share a before/after reload screenshot so that one can get an impression of what you see. Keep in mind we don't know anything about your app other than what you posted here. Be a bit more precise about the problem.

Comment: Thank you, problem solved when I used bootstrap cdn.

Comment: This is if anything a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: It's a workaround yes but it actually solved the problem, why it wouldn't be a solution then?

Comment: Because the original problem is still there. It just doesn't show anymore because you "worked around it" by not trying to serve your own styles. Using a CDN is obviously significantly different then using styles provided by your own server. So it is not equivalent to the previous solution. A real solution can explain the reason for the failure. If you can't explain why something did not work you don't have a solution. You have a workaround. Short term this may be satisfying but long term you will run into problems if you refuse to understand your own system.

Answer (score -1):

Use This:-

```
if (this.state.login) {
     this.context.router.push(`/itemSelection/${this.state.id}`);
}
```

Comment: How is this an answer to OP's question?